# Convert the data stored in db in string format to object datetime

Tags: php, laravel

The data that front-end stored the information to database is like this:

```
"recurring_pattern": "{\"freq\":\"1\",\"from_date\":\"2018-10-22\",\"pattern\":\"BYMONTHDAY=4;COUNT=5;\",\"interval\":\"1\"}"
```

And i am step by step doing the convert the string in column recurring_pattern into object datetime. First i check the event is recurring and event_type_id is 2

```
$recurring_pattern = Events::select('recurring_pattern')
        ->where('event_type_id', 2)
        ->where('is_recurring', 1)
        ->first();
```

When i use dump($recurring_pattern) they still show the data, but i cant use RRule to convert the recurring_pattern data column into datetime.

I have installed the RRule. I am comparing the inputted day with the recurring_pattern. Thank you

Comment: what is RRule ? I think you need to use `json_decode` and use `Carbon` library

Comment: This one is stored in string, front end they use RRule Generator online and save into db in string. And since it is recurring events so cannot use Carbon. That's why i use RRule framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [PHP-RRule](https://github.com/rlanvin/php-rrule) to parse the string on server side and do comparing.

Example:

```
use RRule\RRule;

$recurring_pattern = Events::select('recurring_pattern')
                        ->where('event_type_id', 2)
                        ->where('is_recurring', 1)
                        ->first();
$rrule = new RRule(json_decode($recurring_pattern['recurring_pattern']));

// Use PHP-RRule Functions To Do Comparing
```